# Sprite Kit and IOS Development

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

Just a few questions which I can't find answers to anywhere:

1. To code games for IOS using Sprite Kit, do you also need to know Objective-C or Swift?
2. Can you code high quality games without knowing Objective-C or Swift?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. SpriteKit is an Apple framework developed for Objective-C / Swift application. So, yes you'll need at least some code basics notions.
2. "Yes". You might be able to develop game with Unity2D for example, but that would include using another language to write your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to expand a little bit previous answer.

1. SpriteKit is an Apple framework developed for 2D/3D games. It uses Swift or Objective-C. Advantage of using this is that you can be 100% sure that this game will work flawlessly on iOS devices. Disadvantage is that you are locked only to iOS devices. If you have 0 knowledge of Swift or Objective-C, and you wish only to develop for iOS, I would choose Objective-C. It seems a little harder to learn and understand, but compared to Swift to it seems that Objective-C is still (and will be for long time) superior to Swift. Although, it just be my personal preference, because I truly hate Swift. (You can achieve same things in both languages) :)
   I started this way, I do not regret.
2. You can develop games and apps for iOS without knowledge of Objective-C or Swift. You can use programs like Unity, Unreal engine, Corona, Cocos2D/3D. However these programs require learning another language to write your game (c++ or something else). You can also use GameSalad for 2D games. It requires 0 coding, many things are drag and drop, but you do need to understand logic behind it. For example, it wouldn't be programming but it would be coding :)
   GameSalad is easy to learn, fun as well, but forget that you will be able to create any serious game logic or more advanced game than 2D platform one. I tried it, but very soon changed to Objective C and XCode.

If you decide to go with learning actual language (which I would strongly suggest), I would recommend either Objective-C or to learn Ionic software. Ionic uses javascript, but when you learn how to make games/apps you can easily distribute it to ANY platform: iOS, Windows mobile, Android...XCode is better software, but learning Ionic has huge advantage, and that is single click to deploy app on any platform.

Good luck.